# Calling a another controller inside a view - Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created this plunker
http://plnkr.co/tVMVGdbPtJ05wR2WPwbi

The idea is the user list can be created from every controller by using the directive.

```
app.directive('userHtml', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            user: '=',
        },
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: 'user.html'
    }
});
```

And the template

```
<span>ID: {{ user.id }}</span>
<span><a href="#" onclick="StatsCtrl.viewData()" data-id="{{user.id}}">Name: {{ user.name }}</a></span>
```

Inside the directive template I want to show more data of the user. So I created a controller for this

```
app.controller('StatsCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  $scope.data = '';

  $scope.viewData = function() {
    $scope.data = 'Hello World';
  }

}])
```

So I made my links in the directive as `onclick="StatsCtrl.showPlayer()"` but Im just getting "StatsCtrl is not defined"

What is the correct method to do this?

Comment: Where do you define the directive? There isn't in the html.

Comment: My directive is in the script.js file http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/tVMVGdbPtJ05wR2WPwbi/script.js

Comment: I see, but you aren't calling it in the HTML it should be `<a href="#" onclick="StatsCtrl.viewData()" user-html data-id="{{user.id}}">Name: {{ user.name }}</a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you specify use `StatsCtrl` as your directive's controller?

I have a better idea !!!

You can pass your controller objects to your directive, so that your directive can get this data always at anywhere with in the scope of your data.

Say,

You want to use details of all users in your directive. You can pass this object to your directive directly.

```
<my-directive user-data="myScopeVariable"> </my-directive>
```

Here, the variable `myScopeVariable` is a variable of your existing controller and it contains the details of all users.

```
myApp.Controller('myController', function($scope){
    $scope.myScopeVariable = []; // may be a list of user details
});
```

And your directive should be look like this,

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function(){
    return {
        scope : {
           userData : '=' // here you are specifying that you have an attribute with name 'user-data' and convert it's value to my directive's scope as $scope.userData
        },
        restrict: 'AE',
        templateUrl: 'user.html',
        link : function (scope, element, attrs){
             // this is your directive's controller
             // Here you can get user details as
             scope.userData;

             scope.ViewData = function(){
                 // This is your custom function
             }
        }
    }
});
```

So, now you can use `userData` as list or object of your user details,

```
<span>ID: {{ userData.user.id }}</span>
<span><a href="#" onclick="viewData()" data-id="{{userData.user.id}}">Name: {{ userData.user.name }}</a></span>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Is not the directive there is a problem.
What I want is inside the directive call a controller, but this directive is used in multiple controllers.

Comment: Oh, I didnt see the viewData inside the link - that looks correct - Though how do I get the a controller here (or actually I need the $http from a controller, because my directive on the link loads some data from a API

Comment: Ahh the link function does actually take 4 arguments, where the fourth is a controller instance

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly, a directive needs to access data which you have on a controller? Then put that data on a service, a service being a singleton you can inject it in the controller *and* the directive and then both can access that data.

The way you are doing it now is wrong in several ways. You cannot call the controller like that without using 'controller as' syntax, and you can't and would not want to be dependent on parent child scope inheritance for getting to data.

Comment: No, the directive just sends a ID to another controller via a method call.

Answer (score 0):

Change user.html:

```
<span>ID: {{ user.id }}</span>
<span><a href="#" onclick="StatsCtrl.viewData()" data-id="{{user.id}}">Name: {{ user.name }}</a></span>
```

To:

```
<div ng-controller="StatsCtrl">
<span>ID: {{ user.id }}</span>
<span><a href="#" ng-click="viewData()" data-id="{{user.id}}">Name: {{ user.name }} {{data}}</a></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Nope, it does not work - no errors though, but the ng-click does not work.

Comment: With just onlick, then viewData() is not defined

Comment: The viewData() is defined in your controller (StatsCtrl). When used <div ng-controller="StatsCtrl"> in template function viewData is defined. Look this: http://plnkr.co/edit/S4xWfnI7dgDKFZKiQ0q7?p=preview